# Move Static External IP Address to a different of mine

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We ended up having many projects, and management wants us to move resources into a single project. We can move the data and VMs to single project via snapshots.. We will recreate the load balancers in the other project.. However, we are puzzled with external IPs in these projects.. How do we move them? All the projects are owned by our team, permissions is not a problem.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until now it's not possible.  You can't move the external IPs between projects.
There is an open feature requesting ([link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67726921))